# Lottery Ticket Question

Tags: probability, permutations, data-analysis

A lottery ticket contains six different numbers, chosen from 1 to 39. The winning ticket will match all six numbers in the correct order, plus a bonus number, which may match the other six numbers. The second prize matches the six winning numbers in the correct order, but not the bonus number. What is the probability of winning first or second prize?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The portion "plus a bonus number, which **may** match the other six numbers. The second prize matches the six winning numbers in the correct order, but not the bonus number", clearly suggests that the bonus number is separately drawn from the $39$ numbers.

Thus there are two cases:

- $\underline{Bonus\; number\; is\; among\; the\; six\; on\; the\; ticket}$

You can win only the first prize, with $Pr = \dfrac{1}{39\cdot38\cdot37\cdot36\cdot35\cdot34}$

- $\underline{Bonus\; number\; is\; outside\; the\; six\; on\; the\; ticket}$

You can win the second prize, with $Pr = \dfrac{38}{39}\times\dfrac{1}{39\cdot38\cdot37\cdot36\cdot35\cdot34}$

You can win the first prize, with $Pr = \dfrac{1}{39}\times\dfrac{1}{39\cdot38\cdot37\cdot36\cdot35\cdot34}$

Answer (score 5):

Edited: just saw that they had to be **different** numbers

The of winning first or second prize is simply the chance of winning the second prize, or $\frac 1{39*38*37*36*35*34}=\frac 1{2349088560}$ , because the chance of winning first prize is just one of the 39 ways to match six numbers with random bonus numbers.

Comment: Figured out the probability by doing what?

Comment: I feel like there's so much work that should be put into the question, I figured out the probability of winning by multiplying 39*38*...*34 since there's 6 numbers that need to be arranged. But, I don't know how the bonus number will be incorporated.

Comment: If the numbers have to be different, then it would be 39*38*37...etc but if they can be the same it's 39*39*39...etc

Comment: So, for the probability of winning the first prize, you'd have to do 1/39^7 ?

Comment: ____Yes________